# PHP Image display using POST URL

Tags: php, mysql, post, imgur

The popular image hosting site Imgur is great and I'm new to PHP. I'm just wondering how they manage to get an image to display in the page when entering a URL such as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfUDg.jpg

How does the script know to display a certain image from `yjg8v`? Are they using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`?

Newbie here, not trying to be spoon fed, willing to read and study, just cant find much help on the internet about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sites like imgur.com often "clean URLs" instead of traditional URLs with parameters.

Before clean URLs, you would see something like:

```
imgur.com/image.php?id=yjg8v
```

In your script, you can access the parameter via

```
$_GET['id'];
```

To produce clean URLs, you can use mod_rewrite in Apache (or a similar technology in your chosen web server) to map '/gallery/yjg8v' to '/image.php?id=yjg8v'.

You can find additional mod_rewrite information [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/).

Comment: And I'm guessing that the ID is in reference to an image URL stored in  MYSQL?

Comment: It could be, but it may also be an image name or any other type of unique identifier.

Comment: Yeah its just I'm getting users to upload a file, so the ID will reference a file path in the database. Thanks man, really appreciate the help :D

Answer (score 2):

`yjg8v` is a parameter being passed to a script called `gallery`. It doesn't look like a normal query string because there are various ways of coding a website and the normal query string cab look like a directory structure to the casual observer but actually be running through a front controller or mod_rewrite to get the parameters from the URL like a query string.

This [SitePoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/) is a bit old but demonstrates how this would work with mod_rewrite perfectly.

You can also use [Apache's ForceType to accomplish this purely through PHP](http://www.websitepublisher.net/article/search_engine_friendly_urls/3)

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier for you, this is called url rewrite, so the real url is like:
http://imgur.com/gallery/view.php?image=yjg8v

then use
$_GET['image']